# Why does not my post request to an API using Guzzle not work?

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am trying to make a post request to the example URL endpoint. When I make a post request in my localhost, it works fine, but when I try to request live serve with the same come, it returns null every time. So if I make a request that time, my end point gives a response, but it returns null when I make a post request.

```
public function saveEnquiry($request)
{
    $ClientObj = new Client();
    $url = 'endpoint_base_url/v1/business/enquiry';
    $data = [
        'name' => $request->name,
        'lastname' => $request->lastname,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'mobile' => $request->mobile,
        'country_code' => $request->country_code,
        'from_page' => $request->from_page,
        'message' => $request->message,
        'package_slug' => $request->package_slug,
    ];
    $body = ['debug', true, 'form_params' => $data];
    
    try {
        $response = $ClientObj->request('POST', $url, $body);
        $res = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        if ($res['success'] == true && $res['data'] != null) {
            /// logic part
        } else {
            throw new TripshifuException($res['message']);
        }
    } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
        throw new TripshifuException(json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in $response->getBody()->getContents()?

Comment: Why are you using Guzzle instead of the Http facade? What laravel version are you using?

Comment: @MisterDebug sir $response->getBody()->getContents() return null in live but in local it is return endpoint api response

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes I am using Guzzle client and I am using laravel 5.8 version.

Comment: Is $response->getBody()->getContents() returns null OR json_decode?